# Windows networking stops working after sleep/hibernation

Tags: windows, networking, windows-update

Windows networking stops working because of sleep/hibernation and starts working again after a reboot.

I have several Windows 11 computers at home, and I keep them updated to the latest patches. These computers are all on the home network, visible from each other and exposing some shared directories. The desktop is always on, but it goes to sleep when not in use. Usually, it can be brought out of hibernation by trying to access a shared directory. Sometimes, however, there is no way to make the desktop visible from the other computers, even if I log on to it to make sure it is online.
I was logged on to the desktop and (separately) the laptop, but I could not see the desktop from the laptop. Once the desktop was rebooted, it was visible again on the network.

Does anyone else notice this behavior on networked Windows PCs?
If so, how can we troubleshoot the Windows networking stack instead of just rebooting the PC?

Updates in response to questions:

1. Network traffic on desktop (from Task manager): 0%
2. Disk: 100%, but the system is responsive (I am on it now). It has two disks in RAID 1, so I guess after hibernation it syncs the disks?
3. ping from laptop to desktop IP returns fine TTL=128, 0% loss. Same in the opposite direction

Knowledge from web searches: "Windows uses a protocol called WS-Discovery to locate services on a network. This protocol sends a multicast request for one or more target services, such as shared folders and printers, to [find network resources](https://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/how-windows-finds-network-resources.html)."

Comment: Updates are not killing your network- your main box is going to sleep.  Fix that.  Keep it on and allow the screen to suspend or turn it on when you need to update

Comment: What does `ping` say from both computers to each other?